# How can I find the file inside the directory in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying server-side js injection for my assignment.
I am able to find the directory names using the command:

```
res.end(require('fs').readdirSync('.').toString())
```

output:

`photos,practice.db,public,routes,fun,server.js,views`

Now I want to look inside the 'fun' directory and read it's file content.
I tried:

```
res.end(require(‘fs’).readFileSync(‘fun’))
```

but it's not working because it's a directory.

Comment: FYI, you never want to use synchronous file I/O in a node.js server request handler).  Never.  It ruins the scalability of your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
res.end(require('fs').readdirSync('./fun').toString())
```

The code you're trying is using `readFileSync` instead of `readdirSync`.

Comment: thanks. Now I got the file name it's havefun.txt . How can I look into it's content now?
res.end(require(‘fs’).readFileSync(‘havefun.txt’)) not working

Comment: `res.end(require('fs').readFileSync('./fun/haveFun.txt').toString())`